# Laravel Timestamp calculation

Tags: php, laravel, sqlite, timestamp

I would like to calculate the difference between the current time and a timestamp, the timestamp is a date of birth(17/10/1996) and it should display the age of the user(18), any suggestions? I am using sqlite3.

Edit:
Question above has been answered, just another question with the same topic, how do I pass the result from `{{$user->DOB}}` into the php below it? this way I'll be able to get the specific date of birth of a user.

```
   @foreach ($users as $user)
          <div id="friendspanel"class="panel panel-default">
        <a class="searchFriendsLink">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <img src="{{ asset($user->image->url('thumb')) }}">
            <p style="">{{ $user->fullname }}</p>
            <p id="commentP">{{ $user->email }}</p>
            {{$user->DOB}} /// how do I pass this variable into the php below
            <?php
            $created = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', '1/1/1'); // $timestamp = 17/10/1996
            $now = Carbon::now();
            $result = $created->diffInYears($now) . " years old";
            echo $result;
            ?> 
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel bundles with [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) which is very good for date manipulations. You can achieve this with the following code, using Carbon:

```
$created = Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $timestamp); // $timestamp = 17/10/1996
$now = Carbon::now();
echo "You are " .  $created->diffInYears($now) . " years old";
```

As you can see very easy and clean.

For **Laravel 5** you must reference the class like this:

```
$created = Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $timestamp);
$now = Carbon\Carbon::now();
echo "You are " .  $created->diffInYears($now) . " years old";
```

Comment: Edited my question for a similar problem

Comment: Just replace 1/1/1 with $user->DOB

Comment: its now a problem of "A two digit day could not be found Data missing" tried googling it with no answer, any suggestions?

Comment: Well then DOB is not in the format that you have provided. Please post the result of var_dump($user->DOB)

Comment: string(10) "2015-05-13" , prints it out as year month day, but changing that in the formatting didn't fix it, just displays  "A four digit year could not be found Data missing"

Comment: You said that the format was d/m/Y. Change it to Y-m-d and it will work.

Comment: still getting the "A four digit year could not be found Data missing"

Comment: Are you sure all of your users in the loop has dates, maybe someone has missing date or NULL? The code I gave you works just fine you can try with static date.

Comment: deleted everything from my users table and re added date, still didnt work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78685/discussion-between-shaddy-and-thomasmcdonald).